# Download PDF Files with symfony2

Tags: symfony, pdf

I'm trying to download a PDF file from a twig view. render a pdf document as response from my controller.

I 'm using for that Knp-snappy-bundle. But, i have this error:

```
Variable "entity" does not exist in rexBundle:fiche:show.html.twig at line 35
```

this is my controller code :

```
   /* code pour L'EXPORT des fichiers PDF */
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $pdfForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('submitFile', 'file', array('label' => 'Télécharger PDF'))
        ->getForm();

    if ($request->get('pdf_action') == 'download PDF') {

          $pdfForm->bind($request);

          $html = $this->renderView('rexBundle:fiche:show.html.twig', array(
                     'ma fiche'  => $entity
          ));

        return new Response(
            $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
            200,
            array(
                'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
                        ));
    }
```

this is my view code

```
                  <form action="" method="get" {{ form_enctype(pdfForm) }}>
                <input type="submit" name="pdf_action" value="download PDF"/>
            </form>
```

and this is the line 35 in the  show.html.view :

```
    {{ entity.titreFiche }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the bundle but the problem is probably in line

```
'ma fiche'  => $entity
```

You add the entity object to the variable "ma fiche". If you change the line to

```
'entity'  => $entity
```

it should work.

It can't find the variable `entity` because you are not defining it anywhere in the code you posted. (Twig variable != php variable)